# error in age printing while inputting more than 2 data

Tags: c, hashtable

I was asked to make a hash table program which input name and age. I declared name and age as char. While doing the view() function, if I input more than 2 data, for example I input 3 data, the age of the first data does not print, if I input 4 data, the age of the first and the second data do not print. Is there any problem with my code?

```
void view(){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int count = 0;
        struct data *temp = chain[i];
        if(chain[i]!=NULL){
            printf("=== index %d data ===\n", i);
            //struct data *temp = chain[i];
            while(temp!=NULL){
                printf("data %d\n", count);
                printf("name=%s    age=%s\n", temp->name, temp->age);
                temp = temp->next;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: From where you get chain ?

Comment: Impossible to comment on such incomplete code. Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Printing an age as a string is suspicious. Isn't that some integer type instead? But as you don't show most of the relevant parts, this is only guessing.

Comment: If you specifically mention "inputting more than 2 data", the input part would be relevant.